# When an injured character gains a level, how are hit points handled?

Tags: character-advancement, adnd-2e, hit-points, character-levels

I'm used to the party having healers, but I'm running a game right now where a character was injured brutally, down to 1 hit point and they made it to an Inn. They healed somewhat while resting and got into a fight which brought them up to the next level.

When do they get their new hit points? Immediately or after they finish healing the old damage?

Comment: the character in question is a 2nd edition fighter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Add the hit points from leveling up to current hit points

The *Dungeon Master's Guide* (1993) for *Advanced Dungeons & Dragons, 2nd Edition* on Effects of Experience, in part, says

> When a character earns enough experience to attain the next level for his character class, he immediately gains several benefits (unless the optional rules for training are used). The character gains an additional die of hit points (or a set number of hit points at higher levels). These [hit points from leveling up] are added to *both* his current hit point total and his maximum number of hit points. (48–9 and emphasis mine)

It appears that in the campaign the question describes, you're *not* using the optional training rules, so these rules should apply.

However, this is only the default method. The *DMG* presents several alternatives on how and when to award experience and on how and when to allow leveling up, so you needn't feel constrained by these rules if a different way works better for you.